# Can one systematically reduce sentence into information packages/towers?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

On todays wikipedia [front page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), in the *did you know...* section, it says

> Did you know...
>
> ... that Niels Kaas was the chancellor of Denmark during the late 1500s?

Now I find this to be somewhat amusing, since I'm fairly sure not too many people know anything about *Niels Kaas*. This is basically a new name to me. So after I read the sentence it basically says

"Did you know that Denmark had a chancellor, especially during the late 1500s and that reference(*chancellor of Denmark during the late 1500s*) was refered to as Niels Kaas?"

Okay, so to summarize, at least what I get from the sentence is the information that Denmark had a chancellor, and then that this fact is appearently true for the late 1500s.

Now I wonder, is there a systematic way of getting this tower of informations from a sentence, like algorithmic, or do I have to "think"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to this question.

On a practical level, this is being done every day, and there are AI researchers who have developed very effective heuristics that are able to mine information from text.  A search of the computer science literature can point you to the appropriate research and algorithms, etc.  The results are good enough for many everyday purposes.

However, from a more properly philosophical standpoint, the task is impossible, for reasons pointed out by (among others) Wittgenstein at the beginning of his *Philosophical Investigations*, or by Jacques Derrida in his essay "Signature Event Context."  There is no *systematic* way to *rigorously* derive the meanings intended by a text, as the meaning is determined by context, and context is never saturated.  There is always the necessary possibility of ambiguity and misunderstanding.